# Permanently tie files to specific changelists in Rider

Tags: rider, changelist

I have a project that I am working on in Rider. I have 2 solutions, one of which is a class library solution and the other is a WPF solution. I have made 2 separate changelists and I toggled the "Track Changes" on but after each commit any following changes result in all my files defaulting to the default changelist.

How would I go about having a changelist specifically for my WPF solution and another separate changelist for my class library where I would not need to manually assign all files to a separate changelist after a commit and they would automatically show back up in the correct changelist?